# Can't identify cause of small glitch: File Dialog Opening When Loop Starts

Tags: python, tkinter

I've just started learning coding with the intent to build a "simple" text analyzer. I've been studying and practicing all week and for a few dozen hours so far. I'm surprised that I've gotten this far without asking a question(and goodness have I paid for it in guesswork), but now I've come across a recurring problem. Due to my lack of experience and knowledge of programming, I can't seem to identify the cause.

I'm proud to say that the code is actually a successful, working code. My goal was to place the filepath that you get from fdialog.askdirectory and setting it to the entry box, and I accomplished that goal. However, for some reason now, the file dialog opens when I start the loop. This problem came up before, and I solved it totally by accident; But because I'm still learning the program(Pycharm), I ended up losing the code before I could study it and compare the broken one to the fixed one. I would not like for the file dialog to open when the program starts. What in my code is causing this? Thank you for any advice and suggestions!

I've tried removing the "fdialog..." from the var.set, but that unbinds it from the entry box(and notably stops the fdialog... from opening on loop start.)
I've tried different fdialogs but that doesn't stop the dialog from opening.
I've tried moving my var.set(...) to the bottom of the code, but that doesn't do anything.
And many other things when you have no idea what you're doing.

```
    from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog as fdialog

root = Tk()
root.title("Text Analyzer")

root.configure(background='silver')
root.geometry('600x800')

def button_trigger():
    fdialog.askdirectory()

button = Button(root, text="Directory", foreground="black", command=button_trigger)
button.pack(pady=10)

var = StringVar()
var.set(fdialog.askdirectory())

entry = Entry(root, width="50", textvariable = var)
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are explicitly opening the fdialog at loop start by manually calling `askdirectory`. As far as i can see, it should open when the button is clicked. So, you must create the `StringVar` at the beginning, and call `var.set` in the callback function of the button :

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog as fdialog

root = Tk()
root.title("Text Analyzer")

root.configure(background='silver')
root.geometry('600x800')
var = StringVar()

def button_trigger():
    var.set(fdialog.askdirectory())

button = Button(root, text="Directory", foreground="black", command=button_trigger)
button.pack(pady=10)

entry = Entry(root, width="50", textvariable = var)
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank You Programmer! I think I understand what you're saying, but I don't know how to verbalize it back to you. I have a lot to learn about the "vocabulary" and "grammar of all of this.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly! I'm still going to need to learn more syntax before I understand what's happening, but for now I think I see where you're coming from. I found a program that teaches Python code, so now I will have some guidance and structure on learning the basics empirically. Thank you for your help!

Also, I'm not sure how to set the answer as answered, but if a moderator does that then this one has been answered.